Correct way to graceful shutdown infinite async task running parallel and FastAPI
Following code is working correctly.
I am interested is this correct way to graceful shutdown FastAPI and infinite async task that is running in parallel.
import os
import asyncio
import signal
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI


previous_signal_handler = None
init_shutdown = False
infinite_1_done = False


def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    print(f'{signal.Signals(signum).name=} {signal.strsignal(signum)=}')
    global init_shutdown
    init_shutdown = True

    global previous_signal_handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, previous_signal_handler)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM) 


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    print(f'Before yield is shutdown {os.getpid()=}')
    
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    global previous_signal_handler
    previous_signal_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    _ = asyncio.create_task(infinite_1(), name='my_task')
    print(f'Before yield {_.done()=}')

    yield
    
    # wait for infinite_1 to finish
    global infinite_1_done
    while infinite_1_done is False:
        print('waiting...')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    print(f'After yield {_.done()=}')
    print('After yield is shutdown')


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/hi/{wait_time}") 
async def greet(wait_time: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_time) 
    return f"async Hello? World? after {wait_time}"


async def infinite_1():
    c = 0
    global init_shutdown
    while init_shutdown is False:
        c += 1
        print(f'infinite_1 call {c=}')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

    global infinite_1_done
    infinite_1_done = True
    # print for final shutdown
    print(f'Shutdown infinite_1 {init_shutdown=}')

This is just prof-of-concept.
In real code I would use Class for handling signals and global variables will be inside of that class.
async def infinite_1() is simulating some task that is running in endless loop in parallel to FastAPI.
In my real code is reading redis stream.
I have my own signal handler def signal_handler(signum, frame), that after it is done (inform infinite_1 not to start again when done) is returning signal handling to FastAPI(because FastAPI signal handling wait for all path functions to finish).
My concern is this complicated signal handling needed or it can it be done easier ?
Because first I save default FastAPI signal handling reference, then overwrite signal handling to be my function, and all of this in async def lifespan(app: FastAPI).
When shutdown signal is received I need to inform infinite_1, via global variable init_shutdown, to shutdown, restore original signal handling and send SIGTERM.
After that code execution in continued in async def lifespan(app: FastAPI) after yield where I have to wait for infinite_1 to stop.
Maybe this is only way how it can be done, hoping that there is something less complicated.
